# Embedded youtube video not working on iphone

Tags: html, iphone, iframe, youtube, embed

Whenever I embed a video from youtube in a wordpress post it does not work on the iphone

What happens is that it is unclickable, however if I tap next to the video it sometimes starts playing. I have checked z-index and tried multiple solutions from different websites such as adding text/html etc. Any idea's?

[Here](http://www.frank-a-do.nl/weblog/google-ad-grants/) is the post with the video